# Generating Working Hours using SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server

I have this data and I need to generate a query that will give the output below

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of groupings of rows with 2 separate row_number()s. Have 1 for all the data, ordered by date and second one ordered by code and date. To get the groups separated from the data, use the difference between these 2 row_number()s. When it changes, then it's a new block of data. You can then use that number in group by and take the minimum / maximum dates for each of them.

For the final layout you can use pivot or sum + case, most likely you want to have a new row_number for getting the rows aligned properly. Depending if you can have data missing / not matching you'll need probably additional checks.